# Algorithm for 2-D closest co-ordinates

Tags: algorithm, closest

I know I am doing this wrong, but cannot think of the right way to solve this problem.
I am working with 12 points listed below.
(1,2)(1,11)(7,8)(9,9)(12,13),(13,4),(20,8),(22,3),(23,12),(24,14),(26,7),(31,10)

I divide this into two subsets

Left = (1,2)(1,11)(7,8)(9,9)(12,13),(13,4)

Right=(20,8),(22,3),(23,12),(24,14),(26,7),(31,10)

Further cut down

LLeft=(1,2)(1,11)(7,8)

RLeft=(9,9)(12,13),(13,4)

LRight=(20,8),(22,3),(23,12)

RRight=(24,14),(26,7),(31,10)

Find the min distance on each set.

LLeft (1,2)(1,11) is 9, (1,11)(7,8) is 6.7, (1,2)(7,8) is 8.48

The min is 6.7

RLeft (9,9)(12,3) is 6.70, (9,9)(13,4) is 6.4, (12,3)(13,4) is 1.14

The min is 1.14

LRight (20,8)(22,3) is 5.38 (20,8)(23,2) is 5, (22,3)(23,12) is 9.05

The min is 5

RRight (24,14)(26,7) is 7.28 (24,14)(31,10) is 8.06 (26,7)(31,10) is 5.83

The min is 5.83

So now I have LLeft, RLeft, LRight, and RRight.  What I need to find is LRLeft, RLLEft_Right(value in the middle) and LRRight.This is where I get confused.  The only way I can think of getting LRLeft is to take every point in LLeft and RLEft and find the distance between the two.  Then use that distance and compare that with LLeft and RLeft and this will give me the shortest distance between two point for the left side.  Then I do the same for the right and center.  I am pretty sure there is a quicker and better way to do it, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Finding closest neighbor pair is AFAIK an N^2 problem; what's the context for wanting to do this? You may find some of the possible techniques (with caveats) listed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search

Comment: This isn't a nearest neighbour search. You want to look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem#Planar_case

Comment: @Mr E that shouldn't be a comment, it should be an answer

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem#Planar_case

[Here's a better resource for Step 4](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/ClosestPair.pdf), but to get you started: In the recursion, if we already have minimum distances `d1` and `d2` within the left and right sets respectively, then *if* there is a closer pair of points - where one is from the left and one is from the right set - then we only need to check points within a distance `d` of the dividing line, where `d = min(d1,d2)`.

Comment: I did, I am having trouble understanding how to implement step 4.  How do I choose what point to the left of the line to compare to a point right of the line.

Comment: Added a little more info and another link. If I get time tomorrow and it still isn't working for you I'll write up some more.

Comment: Great link! Learned something today.